# Dagger 2 Named cannot be provided without a @Provides method

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2

Trying to grok Dagger 2 and having an issue with named providers. I have a simple setup as follows:

```
// Module
@Module
class AppModule(private val app: App) {
    @Provides @AppScope fun providesApp() = app

    @Provides @AppScope fun provideSharedPreferences(app: App) = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(app)

    @Provides @AppScope @Named("Uri1") fun providesUri1() = Uri.Builder().scheme("https").authority("authory1").build()

    @Provides @AppScope @Named("Uri2") fun providesUri2() = Uri.Builder().scheme("https").authority("authory2").build()
}

// Component
@AppScope
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AppModule::class))
interface AppComponent {
    fun inject(target: MainActivity)
}

// MainActivity
@Inject @AppScope lateinit var preferences: SharedPreferences
@Inject @AppScope @Named("Uri1") lateinit var uri1: Uri
@Inject @AppScope @Named("Uri2") lateinit var uri2: Uri
```

When rebuilding my project I am given:

```
Error:Gradle: android.net.Uri cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
```

I don't understand why adding the Named qualifier doesn't work for me here. If I remove these I can get an instance of SharedPreferences without issue.

Any insight into what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated!

#### EDIT:

Changes per suggestions with the same results as above.

```
// New module
@Module
class AppModule(private val app: App) {
    @Provides @AppScope fun providesApp() = app

    @Provides @AppScope fun provideSharedPreferences(app: App) = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(app)

    @Provides @AppScope @Tag("Uri1") fun providesUri1(): Uri = Uri.Builder().scheme("https").authority("authority1").build()

    @Provides @AppScope @Tag("Uri2") fun providesUri2(): Uri = Uri.Builder().scheme("https").authority("authority2").build()
}

// Tag annotation
@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class Tag(val tag: String = "")

// MainActivity
@Inject @AppScope lateinit var preferences: SharedPreferences
@Inject @AppScope @Tag("Uri1") lateinit var uri1: Uri
@Inject @AppScope @Tag("Uri2") lateinit var uri2: Uri
```

[Project Repo @ Github](https://github.com/deadpixelsociety/sandbox)

Comment: Hmm, your setup seems fine. Could you try two things? 1) explicitly specify return type as `Uri` for your `provides*` methods. 2) try qualifier annotation (custom annotation itself annotated with `@Qualifier` and used in the same way as `@Named`) instead of `@Named` to differentiate uri's.

Comment: @AndroidEx changed per suggestions, see edited post. No difference in result so far!

Comment: I have not seen scopes on fields before. Try removing the scope in `@Inject @AppScope @Tag("Uri1") lateinit var uri1: Uri`, else I have to agree, it looks fine

Comment: I agree with David on the scope. Plus you don't need to set retention as it's runtime by default in kotlin, saves you one line. I've also never used qualifier annotations with additional fields in them, e.g. you can create `@Uri1` and `@Uri2` annotations and use them...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions insofar David and AndroidEx. Unfortunately the same problem remains. I've added a link to the test project repo at GitHub if a fuller context would help: https://github.com/deadpixelsociety/sandbox. Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think I found the problem (at least I checked out your project and it generated dagger classes correctly). If you need to inject fields annotated with `@Named` or some `@Qualifier` annotation you have to use this kind of syntax:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @Inject lateinit var preferences: SharedPreferences
    @Inject @field:[Named ("Uri1")] lateinit var uri1: Uri // for @Named annotation or...
    @Inject @field:Uri2 lateinit var uri2: Uri // ...for @Qualifier annotation

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        app().component.inject(this)

        println(uri1)
        println(uri2)
    }
}
```

Notice how `@Named` / qualifier annotation goes inside `@field:` (without `@` itself).

Idea borrowed from this [repo](https://github.com/damianpetla/kotlin-dagger-example/blob/master/app/src/main/kotlin/org/loop/example/MainActivity.kt).

Comment: You nailed it! After you said that it makes perfect sense. Thank you for the effort!

Comment: The current syntax is 
`@Inject @AppScope @field:[Named ("Uri1")] lateinit var uri1: Uri `
instead of `@Inject @AppScope @field:[Uri1] lateinit var uri1: Uri`

Comment: @NitroG42 I think you describe a different case, if `@Uri1` is annotated as `@Qualifier` then my syntax was correct. That was just an example, and I didn't specify if I used `@Qualifier` or `@Named` annotation, leaving this implementation to the reader.

Comment: That saved me a ton of time! 10x
Just a note: I don't think the scope annotations are required in the use site.

Comment: Just want to add: `lateinit` is _required_ here. The error still persists for me if I try to inject into non-lateinit, named vars. Only after converting to lateinit fields am I able to build.

Comment: @AppScope annotation was not necessary in my case

Comment: Thank you very much. I was getting crazy with the error :X

Comment: Update 10/28/19: This was fixed in Dagger v2.25. If you use this version, you can just type what wasn’t working before: `@Inject @Uri2 lateinit var uri2: Uri`

Comment: Thank you for this answer, you saved a lot of my time. But can anyone really explain the reason behind this syntax, and why it can't work without @field as it does in Java?

Comment: @AlexBerdnikov It has to do with the default annotation target order https://kotlinlang.org/docs/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets. So, if we don't specify the annotation target explicitly, the target will be the `property`. This is not something Java or Dagger 2 can see or care about, and the public field itself (in Java terms) is not annotated. You can see what bytecode it resolves to with the Intellij's "Show Kotlin bytecode" -> "Decompile".