# How to inject into var in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2

I try to implement Dagger2 into my Kotlin project but I have problems with the `@Inject` annotation.

In Java it looks like this and this works fine:

```
public class FooActivity extends Activity {

    @Inject
    @Named("accessTokenObservable")
    public Flowable<Optional<AccessToken>> accessTokenObservable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        App.getGraph().inject(this);
    }
}
```

But how I have to write the `@Inject` line in Kotlin?

When I use this one:

```
@Inject
@Named("accessTokenObservable")
var accessTokenObservable: Flowable<Optional<AccessToken>>? = null
```

I get this error message:

```
Error:Dagger does not support injection into private fields
```

If I use `lateinit`:

```
@Inject
@Named("accessTokenObservable")
lateinit var accessTokenObservable: Flowable<Optional<AccessToken>>
```

I get this error message:

```
Error:Flowable<Optional<AccessToken>> cannot be provided without
an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
```

What is the right syntax to inject something in Kotlin?

Comment: Take a look at [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36199796/dagger-2-named-cannot-be-provided-without-a-provides-method). Named injections have some special syntax

Comment: thank you @Dimezis

Answer (score 12):

I just use

```
@Inject
lateinit var presenter: ItemsPresenter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    AndroidInjection.inject(this)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    ...
}
```

Without any problems

Comment: Slightly off-topic nitpick but according to https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html  ''AndroidInjection.inject(this);'' should be called before ''super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);''

Comment: This is fine if you have no @name qualifier!

Answer (score 4):

You have to change your injection code like this:

```
@field:[Inject Named("accessTokenObservable")]
lateinit var accessTokenObservable: Flowable<Optional<AccessToken>>
```

, and it will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you provide `Flowable<Optional<AccessToken>> accessTokenObservable` somewhere  in your code?

If not 
`Error:Flowable<Optional<AccessToken>> cannot be provided without
an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.` can be produced. Because you are trying to inject object without provide it.
In this case you need to provide in your injector class:

```
@Provide
@Named("accessTokenObservable")
fun provideAccessTokenObservable : Flowable<Optional<AccessToken>>{
    return yourAccessTokenObservable
}
```

then you need to inject your object in your activity

```
@Inject
@Named("accessTokenObservable")
lateinit var accessTokenObservable: Flowable<Optional<AccessToken>>
```