# Kotlin+Dagger2 @Named annotation in Module provider method usage

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2

I’m having a problem using Dagger 2 @Named annotation in Kotlin that is preventing me from migrating Dagger graph to Kotlin. The problem occurs when I need to inject in a Dagger module method a @Named parameter. In this case I’m not injecting it through a constructor or a field. I’ve tried all [Kotlin annotation use-sites targets](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets) and none of them seems to work in a method parameter. Please, any solution will be very much appreciated. Below is the portion of java code that once converted to Kotlin won't compile:

```
@Module
public final class MyModule {

   (...)

   @Provides
   @Singleton
   LoginStore provideLoginStore(@Named("main_dao_session") DaoSession mainDaoSession, @Named("demo_dao_session") DaoSession demoDaoSession) {
      return new LoginStoreImpl(mainDaoSession, demoDaoSession);
   }

   (...)

}
```

Comment: Maybe this might help: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/761 or this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36211005/6507689

Comment: Nope, the first one is incomplete, referring to https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/668, which I don't really think is related to the @Named issue, and the second one is about its usage in fields, not function parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use-site targets do not apply in this case, since you're dealing with function parameters. The target needs to be specified with constructors because a lot of code is generated in the background for each constructor parameters.

Just use the annotation as you normally would:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideLoginStore(@Named("main_dao_session") mainDaoSession: DaoSession, @Named("demo_dao_session") demoDaoSession: DaoSession): LoginStore {
    return LoginStoreImpl(mainDaoSession, demoDaoSession)
}
```

Comment: That's the first thing I tried with no results, but I will check again. Thanks!

Comment: I tested your solution in a small POC I did and it worked! I don't know why I couldn't follow through with this last time. Thanks!

Comment: I'm still having the problem but I now realized that it is a greenDAO library problem with Kotlin, it is not Dagger's. Thanks again!