# Dagger 2 can't inject from subcomponent

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I know that generally it shouldn't make a difference that this is using Kotlin, but I've run into odd cases where the `@Named` qualifier needed a scope in Kotlin.

I have a `ViewHolderFactory` class that allows me to create a simple mapping of view type -> view holder class:

```
@Singleton
class ViewHolderFactoryImpl @Inject constructor(
        private val viewHolderComponentProvider: Provider<ViewHolderSubcomponent.Builder>
): ViewHolderFactory(mapOf(
        R.layout.view_error to ErrorViewHolder::class.java,
        R.layout.view_soft_error to SoftErrorViewHolder::class.java,
        R.layout.view_empty to EmptyViewHolder::class.java,
        R.layout.view_loading to LoadingViewHolder::class.java,
        R.layout.item_got_it to GotItViewHolder::class.java)) {

    override fun createViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val viewHolder = super.createViewHolder(parent, viewType)
        if (viewHolder is Injectable) {
            viewHolderComponentProvider.get()
                    .viewHolder(viewHolder)
                    .build()
                    .inject(viewHolder)
        }
        return viewHolder
    }
}
```

The ViewHolderSubcomponent is defined below, the goal is to be able to create one subcomponent for each view holder and inject a few things:

```
@ViewHolderScope
@Subcomponent(modules = [ViewHolderModule::class])
interface ViewHolderSubcomponent {

    fun inject(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder)

    fun viewHolder(): RecyclerView.ViewHolder

    @Subcomponent.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun viewHolder(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Builder
        fun build(): ViewHolderSubcomponent
    }
}
```

The ViewHolderModule is defined as:

```
@Module
class ViewHolderModule {
    @Provides @ViewHolderScope
    fun provideSectionTitleViewHolder(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): SectionTitleViewHolder =
            SectionTitleViewHolder(viewHolder.itemView)
}
```

When I run the app I find that the injection didn't work, my `@Inject lateinit var` values are null. Looking at the generated code I can see why:

```
@Override
public void inject(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
  MembersInjectors.<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>noOp().injectMembers(viewHolder);
}
```

There's no `MembersInjectors<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>` created for this subcomponent. I can't figure out how to get this to work. I know that I should be able to inject into objects not created by dagger, I just can't quite figure out what I'm missing here.

Oh, if it helps any, I did make sure to include the `ViewHolderSubcomponent` in my `AppModule`'s list of `subcomponents`

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but if your fields look like `@Inject lateinit var`, they might not wind up as `@Inject`-annotated fields in the class file. I'm still trying to wrap my brain around [how Kotlin handles annotations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html), but try `@field:Inject` just in case, and definitely use it for `@Named` and other qualifier annotations per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36199796/1426891). Also, please post the ViewHolder code: for now it looks like Dagger can't find any `@Inject` fields and until we see it I can't do much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inject(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder)` will always be a no-op, because framework classes (or most libraries in this case) don't have any `@Inject` annotated fields. Dagger will only generate code for the class named in your `inject(MyClass instance)` methods, **not for any of its sub-types**.

So if you have a `ErrorViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder`, then you have to use a component that has a `inject(ErrorViewHolder instance)` method to generate code to inject `ErrorViewHolder`.
To clarify, because it's generated code—and not dynamic reflection at runtime—calling `inject(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder)` like you do with an `viewHolder : ErrorViewHolder` will still try to inject fields for `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`, not `ErrorViewHolder`. And `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` will always be a no-op as mentioned.

You will have to modify your setup quite a bit so that you can provide a specific subcomponent that can inject a specific viewholder, you can't use one "generic" component for different types. You could create a base class between `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` and `ErrorViewHolder`, but then again, you could only inject fields declared (and `@Inject` annotated) in your base class, not the specific child.

Comment: Thanks, this clears it up. I moved my `mapOf` into a new dagger module that creates a map using `@Binds @IntoMap @IntKey(R.layout.view_holder_layout_id)` now everything is working!

Answer (score 0):

The *Kotlin* proptery itself is not known to *Dagger*. What you are trying to achieve could be handled as a field or setter injection. Since a setter is generated with any property I usually go for `@set:Inject`.

```
@set:Inject lateinit var myVar: Type
```

Alternatively you can consider constructor injections. Like this you can define the properties as `val` and private.